# Unable to add Downloadable Product in Magento 1.7

Tags: product, downloadable

I am not able to add Downloadable Products. When I am going to ADD Product then in the dropdown all the options displaying except Downloadable Product. Also in the main admin panel under the SYSTEM menu Magento Connect option is not showing. It was all displaying 3 days ago. But suddenly what happens I could not understand. Please help. I am using Magento 1.7

Comment: Did you modify any core file? Did you install any extension that could do more than it is supposed to do?

Comment: I integrated icici payment gateway. But not sure that the problem is due to the payment gateway integration. As I did not modify any core file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if **Mage_Downloadable** is disabled:

In the Backend:
System > Configuration > Advanced Section > Advanced > Disable Modules Output.

`Mage_Downloadable` needs to be enabled.

Comment: In the advanced section Mage_Downloadable is not displaying

Comment: Oh, I got the issue. Actually the Mage_Downloadable.xml file is missing from app/etc/modules. Anyway, thank as I guessed it from your answer. Thanks